# Objects losing value after function return in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, scope, v8

I have some code that is structured like this for part of a routing application in node.js:

```
module.exports = function Router(){
    var self = this;`
    var ROUTES = {
        "GET": {},
        "POST": {},
        "PATCH": {},
        "DELETE": {}
    };

    self.get = function(path, action){
        return compile_route_listing (path, action, method);
    };

    // this is how I view the routing listings outside of the debugging call below
    self.list = function(){
        console.log(ROUTES);
    };

    function compile_route_listing(path, action, method){
        if(path_valid(path) && action_valid(action)){
            var parts = action.split ("#"); // -> [controller, action]
            var qualifier = new RegExp (compile_route_regex(path), "i");
            var handle   = new ActionHandle (parts[0], parts[1]);
            ROUTES[method][path] = {
                "qualifier": qualifier,
                "handle": handle
            };
            console.log(ROUTES); // debugging call, does same thing as self.list
            return true;
        } else {
            // throws my errors, not relevant here
        }
    };

}; // end Router()
```

The problem that I am having is that inside the compile_route_listing function, the debugging console.log(ROUTES) call displays

```
{ "GET": {"my_path":
                { "qualifier": /some valid regex/i,
                  "action": [object ActionHandler] }
         },
  "POST": {},
  "PATCH": {},
  "DELETE": {}
}
```

...but as soon as the compile_route_listing function returns, the exact same call to console.log(ROUTES) that yielded the above now yields (this time via the self.list() method):

```
{ "GET": {"my_path":
                { "qualifier": {},
                  "action": {} }
         },
  "POST": {},
  "PATCH": {},
  "DELETE": {}
}
```

The valid objects seem to have been replaced/overwritten with empty objects.

My first thoughts were that they went out of scope, so I then tried to change the compiling function to

```
function compile_route_listing(path, action, method){
    if(path_valid(path) && action_valid(action)){
      var parts = action.split ("#"); // -> [controller, action]
      var qualifier = compile_route_regex(path); // just a string
      var handle   = parts; // just an array ["controller", "action"]
      ROUTES [method][path] = {
        "qualifier": qualifier,
        "handle": handle
         };
       console.log(ROUTES); // debugging call, does exact same thing as self.list
       return true;
     } else {
       // throws my errors, not relevant here
     }
   };
```

and both the internal call to console.log(ROUTES) and the external one via self.list() return as:

```
{ "GET": {"my_path":
                { "qualifier": "uncompiled regex string",
                  "action": ["controller", "action"] }
         },
  "POST": {},
  "PATCH": {},
  "DELETE": {}
}
```

What I don't understand is why the types String and Array last through the function return but instantiated RegExp and my custom ActionHandler objects are reset to blank states.

I'd really appreciate some help understanding what the underlying mechanism causing this is... I've spent a couple hours searching online and hsve had no luck finding a solution. Thank you in advance.

-Jake

**EDIT 1**
It was mentioned in the comments that I have not stated how I am accessing the values outside of the function scope, so I've done my best to modify the original language of the post to make this clear.

I am currently unit-testing the creation of the route listings, so I haven't moved on to implementing functions to interact with route handlers yet. I'm still trying to make sure that they save correctly to the ROUTES object, which is the problem here.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the handler?" You've shown how you're setting the handlers but not how you're "accessing" them such that the object is mutated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry if the original post was unclear... I wrote it after having been up all night coding. Hopefully the clarifications I've provided make things more clear!

Comment: [It works for me.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de95b1d2e95da7a2fe3e) There must be something else going on in your code that you're not showing.

Comment: I was working on this project using a virtual environment provided by the cloud9 ide, and when I returned to the code later in the day it was executing properly. I would imagine something was amiss with the output being piped to the browser from cloud9's servers.